# What is the output of expression c=a+++b? If a=2,b=5 in c language...?

Tags: c

Sample Code :

```
int a = 2;
int b = 5;
int c = (a++)+b;
//answer: 7
```

a+++b is evaluated as (a++) + (b), since post-fix increment operator has higher precedence than prefix increment operator.
So the answer would be (2++)+(5) = 7;

Then what if the expression is like a+++b+++5?
Which is giving answer 10, but how?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking since you answered your own question

Comment: If this was suppose to be a tutorial, the answer part should have been posted as an Answer. (There's even a checkbox allowing to type of a question an an answer to it before submitting anything). As it stands, there doesn't seem to be an question. Voting to close as unclear

Comment: Please don't post code as an image.

Comment: @Saurabh P Bhandari, It's not UB. You might be thinking of `a++ + a` which is UB because it both reads from and writes to `a`. C uses the longest sequence that forms a token when tokenizing, so `a+++b` mans `a++ + b`, which is perfectly ok.

Comment: @ikegami, True, whenever I see multiple ```++``` or ```--``` in an expression, the first thought is undefined behavior

Comment: @Saurabh P Bhandari, I'll leave my comment because I'm sure you're not the only one that's going to jump to UB :) (Though there aren't multiple `++` or `--` here.)

Comment: It may not be undefined behaviour,  but I would still fire anyone who wrote code like that or, if in academia, award an immediate F-

Comment: *since post-fix increment operator has higher precedence than prefix increment operator* NO, operator precedence is irrelevant here, `+++` is parsed as `++` `+` because of the scanner specification which interprets the longest matching sequence as a token.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct, but your explanation is not.

The effect of the post increment operation is to increment the variable AFTER the expression evaluation.

Thus

```
c = (a++) + b;
```

is equivalent to

```
c = a + b;
a = a + 1;
```

Operator precedence does not come into play here.